# TailwindCSS padding not applying

Tags: next.js, tailwind-css

```html
<div className="bg-[#fcd34d] aspect-video w-full md:w-8/12 p-1.5 rounded">
    {" "}
    <div className="p-25">MAP</div>{" "}
</div>
```

I want to apply the padding to the parent div but if I increase p- number, the padding for the parent div applies to MAP div.

I also tried to create one more div for the parent div but it did not work. How can I apply the padding to the div with bg?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"p-25" is not a known, predefined value in Tailwind. You can use "p-[100px]" as a custom value, for example:

```html
<div className="bg-[#fcd34d] aspect-video w-full md:w-8/12 p-1.5 rounded">
    <div className="p-[100px]">MAP</div>
</div>
```

You can find the predefined classes here: https://tailwindcss.com/docs/padding